# Distributing summation in an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ be real numbers $\geq 0$. When can I say that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a_{n} + b_{n}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}?$$ Is this true even when $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a_{n} + b_{n}) = \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the numbers you started with are non-negative, you can always say this. Yes, even in the case when the sums are infinite.

Comment: ok, yeah I agree with this.